# Laravel, why using Auth::id() in route file (web.php) returns null?

Tags: php, laravel

I just install fresh laravel application then I proceed making auth by `php artisan make:auth`

The problem is `dump(Auth::id())` returns `null` in route file (web.php) even I already logged in.

It seems fine if

```
Route::get('test', function() { 
    dump(Auth::id()); }
);
```

It returns the current user id that is logged in.

Because I wanted to make a query base on the logged in user id in route file (web.php).

For example (web.php)

```
$test = DB::table('tests')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
dump($test) // returns empty because Auth::id() returns null
```

**Update**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use Middleware to route logged user by ID or role

Comment: Don't check for logged in users in the route. Use a middleware if you need to check if the user is signed in.

Comment: any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It should be `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: You don't really make the query inside the `web.php`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @hs-dev2MR `Auth::id()` works just fine. It's actually better, as it would return `null` instead of warnings/error if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: I think he is putting that exact line directly into the `web.php` file without a route, thats the issue

Comment: So is there any ways to solve this issues?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to achieve (why you put a query there), so we can't really say how to solve it. All we can say is that you cannot use the model in the base `web.php` file without it being part of a route.

Comment: The reason I want to query in web.php (laravel routes) is because each user that logged in can enter the url based on what they keyed in CRUD. All the recorded data is stored in the database. TLDR, I'm experimenting on dynamically create url routes

Answer (score 0):

Read laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

If you want to get user id without auth middleware , try this

For default guard,

```
if ( auth()->check() )
    return auth()->id();
```

For specific guard,

```
if ( auth()->guard('guard-name')->check() )
    return auth()->guard('guard-name')->id();
```

Comment: the problem is, if I log in or not, the `auth()->check` will always return false

Comment: If you are logged in with default guard  `auth()->check()`  will return true. Use `check()` not `check`.

Comment: Even if I logged in or not, its still return false. Look at my updated question

Comment: Put code in controller or route callback function not outside of Route facade.  `Route::get('test', function () { dump(auth()->check());  });` will return true if you are logged in

Comment: but problem is, I need to query before entering the url just like the example i provided in the question